# What would be my best approach to an ASP.NET MVC project with CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, content-management-system

***The Task***

I've been given a task to build an online store. The site would support browsing products, online shopping and a forum. There would be two actors on the site - regular clients and privileged clients(with discounts). The products, sold on the site, would be pulled out from the db of some storage program and queued for modifications (like product name validation, adding missing details, etc) before they are displayed on the site.

That about covers the whole project.

***The Inconvenience***

Except that the client also requires that he can add/remove and edit content on the site.

***What I tough would be a solution***

So, in this case a CMS is what is needed.. Right? At least that's what I tough, tho I never used one. So I looked up some .Net CMSes and I chose Umbraco.

***The Disappointment***

After i saw how Umbraco is used, I no longer feel like this is what I need. I tough that a CMS for .Net would integrate with VisualStudio and not stand in the way of ASP.NET MVC developing. But it did. And now i'm back at point zero, since i have to choose either to use CMS and forget about .net or develop in .net and not being able to edit content...

***The Question***

How do i develop a site in VS using asp.Net MVC and support a CMS? Is that even possible ?

Comment: This is quite weird question. I have managed to use the new Umbraco(v5) with Visual Studio with no difficulties. Maybe you should try Magento or something else?

Comment: @kubal I've installed the new Umbraco project template, but upon opening it, one can clearly see that this is a Umbraco project layout, not an ASP.NET MVC layout. I guess that's only normal, but i want the CMS to act as a complementary on the MVC, not dictating the flow of development. Anyway, I'll research some more tonight and update the info here.

Answer (score 3):

> **Meek**
>
> Usually when you deal with a CMS system you are working within the constraints of what that system allows you to do. For lots of uses this works really well, you create a site full of content and add a plugin for a common feature you want added to the site. Meek takes this approach and reverses it, as developers we commonly create a custom application for a customer, and then they need the ability to manage a limited set of content within it.
>   Then it is up to you to create a simple way to manage some content and images within you application. Using the Microsoft MVC framework Meek makes this task as simple as adding single assembly reference and a web.config entry.
>   http://www.gingerrant.com/meek/

Can't say I've ever used it, but it's the only CMS i've come across which seems to have this goal.

> **MVC Easy CMS**
>   ery often you (as developer) creating websites need their pages and content to be manageable. There are too many free CMS platforms now but all their powerful features are not needed. You need only to write your code and mark some html zones as manageable. It will be nice to do this very quickly and without writing any server code specific for CMS framework. In this case MVC Easy CMS is the product you need.
>
> The main features of framework:
>
> - easy to install and uninstall
> - easy to make your static html to be dynamic using html attributes
> - very good performance of data managing
> - marking of manageable zones can be started at creating html design step
> - website's source code should not be changed during using CMS or after its removing
>
> We support MVC 3 and MVC 4 with Razor as engine and C# as language at first version. We are on our way to implement VB language support.
>
> http://mvceasycms.ism-ukraine.com/

seems rather neat after a quick play with it.  obviously missing a lot of the features of a real cms (versioning etc) but great for a site where you only have a little bit of content that needs updating

Comment: this sound about right, i'll look it up definitely

Comment: It looks like the link to the github is dead - try this instead https://github.com/brianwigfield/Meek

Comment: also may be worth searching for CMS on the nuget gallery.

Comment: http://mvceasycms.ism-ukraine.com/ looks fairly promising too.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, there are plenty samples out in the wild and "we" do it every day: using .net **and** allow our users editing content. That last thing is not a virtue of .net but of a thing called forms in HTML.

By using Umbraco or [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) (MVC) you build your app on top of such a framework and extend it for the needs you have.

Although I doubt that you need a full-fledged CMS for editing productinfo.

Looks like you are however expecting a visual studio addin that generates the site for you.
If so then I would point you google and findout about several websites that offer online shops that you can visually customize **without** the need for programming.

Just sign up, fill in the blanks and y're up and running nice and comfy.

Comment: There's e.g. nopCommerce - free & OS ASP.NET MVC cart that is customizable.

Comment: This is building on top of a CMS/Ecom platform, whereas the author is asking for an addon to an existing MVC site.

Comment: What i expect/need from the CMS is to make some of the content editable (mostly text on pages, nothing serious), as an addition i would like it to handle e-commerce and blog/forum. But the site is not only for presenting, because i need back-end logic for queuing new products and validating them before they can be displayed on the site. The prices would also vary on the client type, and specific customers may have specific discounts, etc... So i don't know if the online shop is gonna work for me

Comment: Seems like there a couple of options ahead. In a nutshell, I really need something (CMS i call it) that could automate as much as it can for me (like e-commerce module with shopping cart, a forum/blog, user-levels rights) and let me do the back-end, server-side logic that is custom and that supplies the actual products, displayed on the site. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Nothing more, nothing less... You want all the modules for free and do you own server-logic? What do you think what's in the modules? YOUR logic already build. I suggest you go out and search a vendor with a turn-key solution. Will cost you but saves everybody a lot of time and agony

Comment: I'm gonna meet with a guy how did key-features of Telerik's Sitefinity CMS this evening and hopefully he'll point me on the right directoin. Will update the page with whatever we agree on. 

P.S. funny thing, the guy and i were in the same class in junior school...